# why this style is not working in wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a style for button as follow:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BlackButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and a button on which is defined as follow:

```
<Button Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="520" Height="34" Width="107" 
        Style="{StaticResource BlackButton}" />
```

But when I run application, I can not see the button. Its background set to none.

If I change the style as follow:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BlackButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>         
</Style>
```

(Removing the template) then the button is shown but its background is not changing.

What is wrong with this xaml code?

Comment: Maybe the empty ContentPresenter in the template?

Comment: @stijn I removed it but no success :(

Comment: There is nothing to paint. Give the Button a text content and it will display the content. For Setting Background, use a border and ContentPresenter inside Border.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your `ControlTemplate` is simply empty, although you have a `ControlPresenter` in it. But since its `Content` property is not set, it's also empty. To have a `Background` you will have to add a `Border`.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BlackButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This should show you something.

Comment: It does show the background correctly, but the inclusion of the `Template` setter means that the button's chrome is lost.  It's not clear from the question if that's what the OP desires though!

Comment: It is doing what I m interested, but if I add some content to button, it is left aligned, how  can I make it centre aligned?

Comment: @mans: Then you could set like this `ContentPresenter.HorizontalAlignment="Center"`. But if you only need the `MouseOver` behavior, you probably should go with Dan's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You've overridden the template of your control in order to set the `MouseOver` trigger.  That means your control template is otherwise empty - and so nothing is drawn for your button.

You can fix that by moving your triggers to the style itself, like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BlackButton">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
  <Style.Triggers>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
        </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>       
</Style>
```

However, what you're likely to run into now is that the button's built-in `MouseOver` animation will override your red background.  You'll see a flash of red, followed by a transition to the default Windows colour.  One way to fix that thoroughly is to take a full copy of the default `Button` template (using Expression Blend is the easiest way to do this) and remove the animations from it.